# Xcode warning is referring to a path that doesn't exist

Tags: xcode, warnings, crashlytics

I have warning on xcode that reads, warning: /Users/blair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/214RBQA6K22QP/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory note: while processing /Users/blair/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/214RBQA6K22QP/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm

I have about 20 warnings like this that are almost identical. The weird thing is that my machine has no user "blair".

Can anyone please help me figure out whats going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting the "debug" key of the "Debug Information Format" in build settings for the Target, to "Dwarf"

[Firebase Crashlytic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios) directs you to set both "debug" & "release" to "DWARF with dSYM file", however i think you have to make a decision whether you actually need it in debug